# How to get a caption on a org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart in my eclipse plugin. The Viewpart has a org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer. Now i want something like a caption over the tree viewer, to provide information of what data is shown in the tree. If caption doesn't describe my need, i want a line of text above the tree viewer to show some text. 
shows my current view 
[image]
red line in this image shows where i want my line of text
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you just want a line of text above the `TreeViewer` the viewer itself does not support this. Instead just use a separate `Label` control to contain the text.

Something like:

```java
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
{
  Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
  container.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  Label label = new Label(container, SWT.LEAD);
  label.setText("Caption");

  TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(container);

  viewer.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
  ....
```

Note that you need to use a `Composite` to contain the multiple controls.

Comment: Hey greg-449, I though of this solution but this does not work, as because of using RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL) the caption appears in the right place but only 1st row of my TreeViewer is visible.
And when my content provider provides data on some action I can see 3 rows and i have to scroll vertically to see the rest of the rows, I want the TreeViewer to span Vertically and take  all the available client space.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably need to use a more complex layout such as GridLayout. Edited answer to show a GridLayout that makes the tree take all available space.